# Android CardView move from one activity to another activity. how?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android and is trying to make a small project. And for making the homepage I have used android CardView.
[here is the homepage view link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0hXC.jpg)
I don't know how to move from main activity to second activity. So, pls help me out in writing the java part.

suppose, I click on the month card view, I must go to another activity. how to do it?
My MainActivity.xml code is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.shubhojit.atry.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/mon"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpink"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="MONTHS"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Find festivals of your favourite Month"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"


    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundpurple"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_terrain_black_24dp"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="PLACES"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/lightgray"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Check out festivals in your Region"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cerclebackgroundgreen"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_people_black_24dp"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="CULTURES"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/lightgray"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Live out with festivals of your own Culture"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to assign ID

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

for the elements on your MainActivity.xml file because you'll need these ID to make an connection to your java class.

Once done, move over to your java class and wire them into the elements in your Java class. Make sure the elements are matching because you cannot have an Image in Java connecting to a TextView in XML. Lets take an image for example (code goes in onCreate method):-

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```

Now create an OnClickListener which is responsible for executing code when you click on myImage element.

```
myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

MainActivity.this is the element which will describe your current activity and AnotherActivity.class is the element which will describe the activity you wish to navigate to.

Please note this is written free handley as I don't have android studio on my laptop currently so work accordingly to the syntax provided within Android studio. Let me know if you need further clarification.